# Disable mobile browsing for a single website in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, mobile

How to disable mobile browsing for a single website in SharePoint 2010 without disabling all of websites in SharePoint?

As far as I know we can disable it as described [here](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2011/02/three-options-for-disabling-the-sharepoint-2010-mobile-redirection-system/) or [here](http://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/how-to-disable-mobile-view-in-sharepoint-2010/). But when applying those instructions, mobile browsing disabled for all of the websites in SharePoint. What I want is to disable it only for a single website like "`mydomain.com/sites/mysite`"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve this with PowerShell script,

```
#Disable Mobile Redirection for all browsers for a given web application

param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, Position=0)] 
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPWebApplicationPipeBind]
            $WebApplication)

# SharePoint cmdlets
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
if([Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")-eq$null){throw "Unable to load Microsoft.SharePoint.dll";}

$WebApp = $WebApplication.Read()

$configMod1 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$configMod1.Path = "configuration/system.web"
$configMod1.Name = "browserCaps"
$configMod1.Value = '<browserCaps><result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter></browserCaps>'
$configMod1.Sequence = 0
$configMod1.Owner = "contoso\administrator"
## SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode -> 0
$configMod1.Type = 0

$WebApp.WebConfigModifications.Add( $configMod1 )

$WebApp.Update()

$WebApp.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications() 

Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

got this script from this article:

http://gavinb.net/2011/06/13/disable-mobile-redirection-for-a-web-application-via-powershell/

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this script works,it is for disabling mobile browsing for all websites in a web application in SharePoint.But i want disable mobile browsing for a single website in a web application not all of the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to identify the mobile device, then use the javascript to redirect the site to specific page saying access denied.

It should be done in a master page.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add a http redirect only for the sub site in web.config using location settings, if you have access to web.config

Ex:

```
<location path="subsite/_layouts/mobile">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
        <add wildcard="*" destination="/subsite" />
      </httpRedirect>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```